# ASP MVC - ConfigurationManager Cannot find Appsettings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mstest

I am using MS Test to test one of my controller's actions. This method uses the ConfigurationManger to read appSettigns from the web.config. For some reason ConfigurationMangager is not able to find the appsettings. In NUNIT I would just make sure to add a copy of the webconfig file to the test project so that it is available when running in that context. However this is not working for me.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to make sure my web.config is where it needs to be when using MS test?

Comment: I believe `web.config` are only read when the project is a web application. Like Anthony said, try `App.config`.

Comment: Just to be clear MS Unit tests look for app.config files not web.config files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using app.config instead of web.config

Comment: MVC 4 doesn't have app.config. Not sure I should create one. I am using few constants in web.config (not many), but they aren't being read properly from Unit Test environment (and they do work as expected when I just run the project)

Comment: You need to add a app.config  to the Unit Test project that has the values you need from the app config section of your web.config. Unit test dont use the web project to run.

Comment: This won't work when the Unit under test is a private method that reads from the Web.Config file.

Comment: @JohnPeters unless you have created your own configuration section your private method could use ConfigurationManager class and let .net figure out what its reading from.